# Can't click date of calendar with style

Tags: c#, date, xaml, silverlight, calendar

I am new on silverlight development. During my activity i have encountered issue which I can't click date of calendar with style. My main purpose is clicking date and display with color. I followed this link [How to customize holiday appearance in the Silverlight Calendar](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kathykam/2009/05/18/how-to-customize-holiday-appearance-in-the-silverlight-calendar-jason-cooke/) and I wrote date click event. But it didn't trigger.

this is .xaml

```
<UserControl
xmlns:ext="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls" 
xmlns:prim="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;assembly=System.Windows.Controls">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CalendarDayButtonStyle1" TargetType="prim:CalendarDayButton">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="prim:CalendarDayButton">
                    <Grid Background= "{Binding Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConverter}, Path=Date}">
                        <ContentControl x:Name="Content" Margin="5,1,5,1" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have provided the grid inside the control template, click is occurring on the grid level. What I have done is changed from grid to Button.

```
<Style x:Key="CalendarDayButtonStyle1" TargetType="CalendarDayButton">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="CalendarDayButton">
                    <Button Background= "{Binding Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConverter}, Path=Date}">
                            <ContentControl x:Name="Content" Margin="5,1,5,1" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                     </Button>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Thanks,

Satish Pai

Comment: I added your changer but There is error The name "CalendarDayButton" does not exist in the namespaces "http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007"

Comment: Have you added the<ControlTemplate TargetType="prim:CalendarDayButton"> or just <ControlTemplate TargetType="CalendarDayButton"> ? If not add it with prim:

Comment: It is same as my previous work??? But clicking event did not trigger?????